# data from edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am getting the data of edit text fields like this:

```
 editfield1.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
```

then

```
 @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||(event.equals(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))||(event.equals(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER))){
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            String data= editfield1.getText().toString();
        }
    }
```

This is working fine for some android device samsung 2.2. because to get each edit field 
some key event must be there.

But if I try to run in micromax 4.0, not able to get the data from all edit fields.
because here i can touch each edit field and write the value.. so no key events.

How can I solve this.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to track each change in your TextView/EditText, don't you?
You may use [addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) to keep track of changes. I'll add an example if you need one.

Edit:
You can implement some kind of wrapper for handling multiple text views:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        attachTextViewWatcher(R.id.text1);
        attachTextViewWatcher(R.id.text2);
        attachTextViewWatcher(R.id.text3);
        attachTextViewWatcher(R.id.text4);
        attachTextViewWatcher(R.id.text5);
        // tbc...
    }

    private void attachTextViewWatcher(int resId) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(resId);
        tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextViewWatcher(tv));
    }

    private void onTextChanged(TextView v, CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO do your stuff
    }

    private class TextViewWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private final TextView tv;

        public TextViewWatcher(TextView tv) {
            this.tv = tv;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // ignore
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // ignore
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            MainActivity.this.onTextChanged(tv, s, start, before, count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The activity contains a form which have more then 16 edit text filed. So text watcher is giving problem in getting data for specific text fields. Thanks for ur response..

Comment: I've added a code example for you how you could keep track of each text view.

Comment: Thanks a lot . But I fixed it by using TextWatcher().

Comment: Well my example is an TextWatcher implementation ^^